# How to change the language of inserted or updated paths to LANGUAGE_NONE using a module?

Tags: 7, hooks, path-aliases

All path aliases are entered by hand. I need them to be language independent. Currently they are created/updated in the language that the user is currently using which does not make sense in case of my site.

I tried using hook_path_insert and hook_path_update but they only receive the $path by value and not by reference and changing the function to hook_path_update(&$path) results in an error.

How to change the language of inserted or updated paths to LANGUAGE_NONE using a module? Alternatively, how can I force all aliases to be language independent automatically when user enters them? I don't think it is not possible; it is possible to allow them to choose the "All" language, but not force it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone needs to have a multi language site, but have all URL aliases language independent (i.e. the same for all nodes and languages), the solution is to create a function:

```
mymodule_node_validate($node, $form, &$form_state) { 
   $form_state['values']['language'] = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
}
```

As a side effect, it also makes all nodes language independent. One possible scenario where this would be useful is:

- all nodes are created in a custom language which is also the site default language
- the administration interface is in English (this so far requires multi-language)
- the administrator users are able to use the same URL aliases as the rest of site visitors, despite the fact that they have English set while the content is in a different language (this requires the trick)

In a real multi-language scenario, URL aliases may need to be different for different languages.

Answer (score 0):

[This comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/321848#comment-8382941) on drupal.org provides exactly what you were looking for.

Create a new module called `neutral_paths` and make this the content of `neutral_paths.module`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_alias_alter().
 *
 * Resets the language before saving the alias
*/
function neutral_paths_pathauto_alias_alter(&$alias, array &$context) {
  // Force all aliases to be saved as language neutral.
  $context['language'] = LANGUAGE_NONE;
}
?>
```

This hook is more specific than the one posted in the other answer so it will be called only when needed.